# Spotify web player - updating url without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

i was on Spotify's web player and was looking to build a similar website.

Everything on their i understand except how they can update the url without refreshing the entire page. I know how to do this with hashtags but they do not use this!

does anyone have any idea how they do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to be using the HTML5 `onpopstate` event that is implemented using JavaScript.

See this article, [HTML5: Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/), which explains all.